# Allow a stateless function to accept multiple different prop interfaces

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How do I allow a function to accept multiple different prop interfaces? In the example below I want it to accept either `IFlatProps` or `IChildrenProps`. I tried something like below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
const Field: React.SFC<IFlatProps | IChildrenProps> = ({
  label, name, helpText, children
}) => (
  // ...
);
```

The interfaces look like this:

```
interface IFlatProps {
  label: string;
  name: string;
  helpText?: string | JSX.Element;
}

interface IChildrenProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  helpText?: string | JSX.Element;
}
```

edit: The error that I'm getting from typescript is:

> [ts] Type '(IFlatProps & { children?: ReactNode; }) | (IChildrenProps
>   & { children?: ReactNode; })' has no property 'label' and no string
>   index signature

This error is for the `label` property, I also get the same error for the `name` property.

Here's a codesandbox replicating the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/k5o20kvo4o

Comment: What if you union them? `type IFlatOrChildrenprops = IFlatProps | IChildrenProps` and then `React.SFC<IFlatOrChildrenprops>`. I am not sure if this will work out and therefore I did not post it as an aswer. Kindly let  me know

Comment: @MatthewBarbara No, that seems to work the exact same as my code above.

Comment: Added the specific error I'm getting to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by definition, you can only access common fields of a union type, and since some of the fields are not common between the two interfaces you can't  access them and thus you can't destructure them either. The simplest solution is to type the `const` as a `SFC<IFlatProps|IChildrenProps>` but to type the parameter of the function to something that optionally has all members of the union, like `Partial<IFlatProps & IChildrenProps>`

```
const Field: React.SFC<IFlatProps | IChildrenProps> = ({
     label, name, helpText, children // All typed as original type |undefined 
}: Partial<IFlatProps & IChildrenProps>) => (
    null
);
```

For your case this works well as there are no common mandatory properties anyway, so we can consider all properties as optional on the parameter. If we had such properties we could use a more complex type to preserve the fact that such properties should always be present

```
const Field: React.SFC<IFlatProps | IChildrenProps> = ({
    label, name, helpText, children, //these are still optional 
    commonNotOptional //will be just string 
}: Merge<IFlatProps, IChildrenProps>) =>  null;

type Merge<T1, T2> = Pick<T1, Extract<keyof T1, keyof T2>> &
    Pick<T2, Extract<keyof T2, keyof T1>> &
    Partial<T1 & T2>

interface IFlatProps {
    label: string;
    name: string;
    commonNotOptional: string
    helpText?: string | JSX.Element;
}

interface IChildrenProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    helpText?: string | JSX.Element;
    commonNotOptional: string

}
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem I'm seeing now is that the compiler still thinks that `name` and `label` can be `undefined` when `children` is defined. Which is causing me to see the error `Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.` when using `name` deeper in my function. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/k5o20kvo4o

Comment: @DaveJ the compiler is right here. Since the props are either `IFlatProps` or `IChildrenProps` name could be undefined since it does not exist as a mandatory field in `IChildrenProps`. You should provide a default for it where you use it `name || 'default' `

Comment: Yes but that code is unreachable though since it is guarded by a check to see if `children` is defined. This doesn't seem a very nice way of doing things (`name || 'default'`) since `'default'` means nothing and is merely an escape hatch to get it to compile. Perhaps I'm thinking about this the wrong way since I've only been using Typescript for one week... Do you have any other ideas about how I could write this? Perhaps a wrapper function that takes both types of props and two child functions that only take one of either `IFlatProps` or `IChildrenProps`?

Comment: @DaveJ yes probably the simplest solution is to have two functions, and use a custom type guard. In the sample you provide you use an older version of TS. in 2.9 we could use an `in` type guard.

Comment: Do you have a usage example that you can point me to of an `in` type guard? I'm struggling to understand what you mean?

Comment: @DaveJ Sure: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=namespace%20JSX%20%7B%20export%20class%20Element%20%7B%20%7D%7D%0D%0Anamespace%20React%20%7B%20export%20class%20ReactNode%20%7B%20%7D%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20IFlatProps%20%7Blabel%3A%20string%3Bname%3A%20string%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20IChildrenProps%20%7B%20children%3A%20React.ReactNode%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%3A%20IChildrenProps%20%7C%20IFlatProps%3B%0D%0Aif%20('children'%20in%20foo)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo.children%20%2F%2F%20is%20IChildrenProps%0D%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo.name%20%2F%2F%20is%20IFlatProps%0D%0A%7D

Comment: That's perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.